# Setting html form values using js function with multiple attributes

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms, function

In PHP I've got a button with:

```
onclick="myFunction(&value1, $value2, $value3)"
```

JavaScript:

```
function myFunction(atr1, atr2, atr3) {
    document.getElementById('form_input1').value = atr1;
    document.getElementById('form_input2').value = atr2;
    document.getElementById('form_input3').value = atr3;
    document.getElementById('popup_form').style.display = "block";
}
```

But the values are not set. This works fine when I use function without attributes and set value:

```
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById('form_input1').value = "8";
    document.getElementById('form_input2').value = "abc";
    document.getElementById('form_input3').value = "56";
    document.getElementById('popup_form').style.display = "block";
}
```

How should I change my function to set form values from attributes given in php?

Comment: are you passing three php variables in that

Comment: Please show more of your PHP. Off-topic note: they are called **parameters**.

Comment: @George: When editing, always remove fluff like _"Thanks!"_

Comment: @Jurid: `&value1`? Shouldn't that be `$value1`?

Comment: @Cerbrus If the OP has written a paragraph thanking everybody/an introduction to their life then yes, I'll remove it. For one-word politeness, I see no issue in retaining it. I am certainly not going to revoke somebodys opportunity to show good manners, especially when it's so minor.

Comment: @Cerbrus yes, of course it should be $ instead of & my mistake when typing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not too clear from the question, but you are probably getting a syntax error in your javascript, because you are not adding quotes around the variable values. So the rendered javascript will look like:

```
onclick="myFunction(8, abc, 56)"
```

You need to add quotes where appropriate, or just to all of them. Also `&value` should probably be `$value1`.

```
onclick="myFunction('$value1', '$value2', '$value3')"
```

This will render

```
onclick="myFunction('8', 'abc', '56')"
```

Comment: Using quotes fixed it.